# Help deriving optical path

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, refraction, geometric-optics, variational-principle

I have to derive the path of a light ray traveling in a stratified medium with linear variation of its refractive index.
For context the first two exercises ask you to derive Snell's law using Lagrangian formalism, we're in 2D space ($xz$ plane) and  the refractive index is a function of $z$, in this case:
$$n(z) = n_0 + \alpha z.$$
In the previous section you arrive at:
\begin{align}
\frac{n(z) x'(z)}{\sqrt{1+(x'(z))^2}} = \gamma, \\
\frac{n(z)}{\sqrt{1+(z'(x))^2}} = \gamma, \\
\end{align}
where both equations are equivalent to Snell's Law.

Now for the stratified medium problem the book proposes using the last equation, from which we can derive that
\begin{align}
z' & = \sqrt{ \left(\frac{n(z)}{\gamma}\right)^2 -1 }\\
& = \sqrt{ \left(\frac{n_0+\alpha z}{\gamma}\right)^2 -1 }.
\end{align}
Now we have to solve for the differential equation considering the initial conditions $z(0)=z'(0)=0$ and here is where I get confused, they propose to use
$$\frac{n_0+\alpha z(x)}{\gamma} = \cosh (u(x)).$$
My guess was they wanted that since $$\sinh^2(u) - \cosh^2(u) = 1  $$ and thus we can get $$ \sqrt{\cosh^2(u) - 1} = \sinh(u)  $$ which looks almost exactly like the expression we want to solve for $z$ and now they say we can derive that:
$$ \frac{\gamma}{\alpha} u' \sinh(u) = sinh(u) $$
therefore getting that $u'= \frac{\alpha}{\gamma} $. By integrating we can get $u(x)= \frac{\alpha}{\gamma} x + b $ where b is a constant, and from the initial conditions one would get that $\gamma = n_0$ and $b = 0$ Finally getting that:
$$z(x) = \frac{n_0}{\alpha} \left[ \cosh \left( \frac{\alpha}{n_0} x \right) - 1 \right].$$
But yes, I've been unable to get any of those expressions and I'm starting to get desperate, I would really appreciate any help on how to get these, perhaps I'm doing something wrong when using the chain rule, I'm really not sure but I always get something extra or something less,also any other way to solve for $z(x)$ or $x(z)$ would help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it I was making dumb things to impose $\sinh^2(u)-\cosh^2(u) = 1$ that didn't help solve the differential equation.

Since our initial conditions are z(0)=z'(0)=0 , the equation we find useful is: $$ \frac{n(z(x))}{\sqrt{1+(z'(x))^2}} = \gamma $$  so we can solve for the initial conditions easily.

Now, from the last equation we derived the relationship

\begin{align}
z' & = & \sqrt{ \left(\frac{n_0+\alpha z}{\gamma}\right)^2 -1 } \tag{1}
\end{align}

and noticed that $\sqrt{\cosh^2(u) - 1} = \sinh(u)$  looks almost like our equation thus we make the change of variable
$$\frac{n_0+\alpha z(x)}{\gamma} = \cosh (u(x)) \tag{2}
$$
$$ \implies \alpha z(x) = \gamma \cosh (u(x)) - n_0 
$$
$$ \implies z(x) = \alpha^{-1} \gamma \cosh (u(x)) - \alpha^{-1} n_0 \tag{2.1}
$$
thus
$$ z'(x) = \frac{\gamma}{\alpha} u' \sinh (u(x)) \tag{3} $$
now from (2) in (1) we get:
$$ z'(x) = \sqrt{\cosh^2(u(x))-1} = \sinh(u(x)) \tag{4}$$
from eq (4) and (3)
$$ \frac{\gamma}{\alpha} u' \sinh (u(x)) = \sinh(u) $$
$$ \implies \frac{\gamma}{\alpha} u'  = 1 $$
$$ \implies u' = \frac{\alpha}{\gamma}  $$
since u=u(x)
$$ \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{\alpha}{\gamma}  $$
integrating we get
$$ u = \frac{\alpha}{\gamma}x + b \tag{5} $$
The expression (5) plus our initial conditions plugged into the expression (3) yields:
$$z'(0) = 0 =  \frac{\gamma}{\alpha} [{\alpha}{\gamma}] \sinh (\frac{\alpha}{\gamma} 0 + b)$$
$$0 = \sinh(b) \implies b=0$$
then our expression for u(x) is simplified and we can substitute it now on (2.1)
$$ z(0) = 0 = \frac{\gamma}{\alpha} \cosh (\frac{\alpha}{\gamma}(0)) - \frac{n_0}{\alpha}
$$
$$ \implies 0 = \frac{\gamma}{\alpha} \cosh(0) - \frac{n_0}{\alpha} = \frac{\gamma}{\alpha} - \frac{n_0}{\alpha} 
$$
$$ \implies \frac{\gamma}{\alpha} = \frac{n_0}{\alpha} \implies \gamma = n_0
$$

substituting the new information into (2.1) we finally get:
$$z(x) = \frac{n_0}{\alpha} \left[ \cosh \left( \frac{\alpha}{n_0} x \right) - 1 \right]$$